# Data-e2e to list in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tiktok

I'm doing a scraping process using selenium in which my goal is to extract the views, likes, comments and shares of the videos that are made to an audio in TikTok.

In the process I found this path:

```
<div data-e2e="music-item-list" mode="compact" class="tiktok-yvmafn-DivVideoFeedV2 e5w7ny40">
```

This contains the different videos of the audio, however it is inside a `<div>` and not `<li>`.

[div dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en8c0.png)

How do I convert the divs contained in the path into a list that I can manipulate?

This is what I did:

```
url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/music/Sweater-Weather-Sped-Up-7086537183875599110'

driver.get(url)

posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-e2e="music-item-list"]')
post1 = posts[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to locate those elements would be too wait for them in a first instance, and then locate them as a list, then access them:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
[...]
posts = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH , '//div[@data-e2e="music-item-list"]/div')))
for post in posts:
print(post.text)
```

Selenium documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/